I was working on vs code in C++ and suddenly I got an error not showing any output in terminal
I was working on vs code in C++ and suddenly an error appeared that no output was shown in the terminal. I tried
Please help guys, because this error is hindering my work. I was working in oop on large projects, and suddenly this error appeared.
PS C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\C++ oop> g++ test.cpp -o test.exe
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: test.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
PS C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\C++ oop> 


Provide a [mcve]

My advice is to not use spaces in your file or folder names. Keep the folder simple like C:\Programming\C++Project1 also its best to not have your folder on a cloud drive.

The error says that test.cpp does not exist. Do you think that is wrong? Have you tried looking for test.cpp?

The file test.cpp is not in the same working directory (C++ oop in your case).
So please check the path of working directory and the path of test.cpp. They should match if you want to compile and run.
All the best!

The error you're encountering related to the path mismatch.Compiler isnt able to findout the file test.cpp.Please check the path and run on the correct directory

PS C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\C++ oop> g++ test.cpp -o test.exe
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: test.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
PS C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\C++ oop>

text.exe is not running

No such file or directory compilation terminated Means that there is no file named test.cpp in the C:\Users\abdal\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\C++ oop folder. I would believe your compiler when it tells you that the file does not exist. Type dir and see what files exist in that folder.

I could not solve the problem and I did not have time, so I deleted all msys2 packages from the system environment, downloaded and installed the msys2 packages again, and the C++ code began to work in vs code.
Thanks for the help .
